# Java HttpClient - reducing debug output

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to load test an application we've been developing, but our console log is constantly spammed with output. From earlier experience, I've learnt that `System.out.println( )` is a relatively expensive operation, so I would like to reduce the printing to a minimum.

The printing only occurs when the application attempts a Http-post, but we do 100s of them per second. We use Apache's HttpClient 4.5.2 and HttpCore 4.4.5. The application runs on Tomcat 7.

I've tried a lot of different solutions: removing the Tomcat valves, setting the Tomcat logging level, setting -Djavax.net.debug=none, but nothing seems to remove this. Does anyone know what causes these outputs, and how do I turn them off?

The debug output is shown bellow:

```
2016-10-11 15:24:42,942 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] Connection request: [route: {}->http://localhost:8080][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 200; total allocated: 0 of 200]
2016-10-11 15:24:42,956 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] Connection leased: [id: 0][route: {}->http://localhost:8080][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 200; total allocated: 1 of 200]
2016-10-11 15:24:42,958 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] Connecting to localhost:8080
2016-10-11 15:24:42,978 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] CookieSpec selected: best-match
2016-10-11 15:24:42,994 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] Auth cache not set in the context
2016-10-11 15:24:42,995 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2016-10-11 15:24:42,996 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2016-10-11 15:24:42,996 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] Attempt 1 to execute request
2016-10-11 15:24:42,997 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] Sending request: POST /XtService/account/getbalance HTTP/1.1
2016-10-11 15:24:42,997 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] >> "POST /XtService/account/getbalance HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2016-10-11 15:24:42,999 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] >> "Content-Length: 48[\r][\n]"
2016-10-11 15:24:42,999 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8[\r][\n]"
2016-10-11 15:24:43,000 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] >> "Host: localhost:8080[\r][\n]"
2016-10-11 15:24:43,000 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2016-10-11 15:24:43,000 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
2016-10-11 15:24:43,000 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] >> "[\r][\n]"
2016-10-11 15:24:43,001 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] >> POST /XtService/account/getbalance HTTP/1.1
2016-10-11 15:24:43,001 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] >> Content-Length: 48
2016-10-11 15:24:43,001 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] >> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
2016-10-11 15:24:43,001 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] >> Host: localhost:8080
2016-10-11 15:24:43,001 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2016-10-11 15:24:43,001 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2 (java 1.5)
2016-10-11 15:24:43,001 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] >> "categoryid=2"
2016-10-11 15:24:43,256 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
2016-10-11 15:24:43,259 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << "Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1[\r][\n]"
2016-10-11 15:24:43,260 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << "Pragma: no-cache[\r][\n]"
2016-10-11 15:24:43,260 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
2016-10-11 15:24:43,260 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << "Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT[\r][\n]"
2016-10-11 15:24:43,261 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8[\r][\n]"
2016-10-11 15:24:43,261 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << "Content-Length: 83[\r][\n]"
2016-10-11 15:24:43,261 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << "Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2016 13:24:43 GMT[\r][\n]"
2016-10-11 15:24:43,261 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << "[\r][\n]"
2016-10-11 15:24:43,262 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2016-10-11 15:24:43,262 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2016-10-11 15:24:43,263 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
2016-10-11 15:24:43,263 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << Pragma: no-cache
2016-10-11 15:24:43,263 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << Cache-Control: no-cache
2016-10-11 15:24:43,263 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
2016-10-11 15:24:43,263 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
2016-10-11 15:24:43,263 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << Content-Length: 83
2016-10-11 15:24:43,263 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << Date: Tue, 11 Oct 2016 13:24:43 GMT
2016-10-11 15:24:43,265 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] Connection can be kept alive for 10000 MILLISECONDS
2016-10-11 15:24:43,274 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] << "{"status":1,"data":{"RESERVED":569.81}}"
2016-10-11 15:24:43,275 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] Connection [id: 0][route: {}->http://localhost:8080] can be kept alive for 10000 MILLISECONDS
2016-10-11 15:24:43,275 DEBUG [http-bio-8080-exec-3] Connection released: [id: 0][route: {}->http://localhost:8080][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 200; total allocated: 1 of 200]
```

Comment: You could have a look at : https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html. Nutshell : find which logging implementation is used (e.g. log4J ?), find its config file, and reduce the org.apache.http(.wire) categories.

Comment: Ah, there we had it. Log4J was configured to output wire-debug to console.  I've been struggling with this for about two hours now. Thank you. I recommend you post an actual answer so I can tick it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a look at : http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html.

> Therefore HttpClient utilizes the logging interface provided by the Commons Logging package. Commons Logging provides a simple and generalized log interface to various logging packages. By using Commons Logging, HttpClient can be configured for a variety of different logging behaviours. That means the user will have to make a choice which logging framework to use. By default Commons Logging supports the following logging frameworks:
>    - Log4J
>    - java.util.logging
>    - SimpleLog (internal to Commons Logging)

The vast majority of the output you observe is actually the "wire" logging (that is, the actual HTTP trafic) :

> The wire log is used to log all data transmitted to and from servers when executing HTTP requests. The wire log uses the `org.apache.http.wire` logging category. This log should only be enabled to debug problems, as it will produce an extremely large amount of log data.

In a nutshell : find which logging implementation is used (e.g. log4J ?), find its config file, and reduce the `org.apache.http(.wire)` categories